# Parsing notification emails

Tags: paypal

I currently use a Paypal button on my website. When a customer clicks the button, they are taken to Paypal's website to make the purchase. Once the purchase is complete, I am sent an email notification by Paypal. The email notice contains a section like this:

Buyer:
Acme Inc
acme@acme.com

Unconfirmed shipping address
John Smith
123 Main Street
Mytown AB  12345
United States

My problem has to do with the fact that there are no field headers to parse this data by.  IOW, I have a back end software program that takes these incoming emails and parses them (or at least, tries to parse them). Problem is, there is nothing telling me what the customer's last name is, or their first name. What if the email contained this?:

```
John de Machio Jr.
123 Main Street
My Town AB 12345
United States
```

Is "Machio" this person's last name, or is it "de Machio", or is it "Jr."?

Is there no way to get field headers with the customer information?  Kind of like this:

```
First name: John
Last name: de Machio
Address line 1: 123 Main Street
Address line 2: Apt. 4
City: My Town
State/province: AB
ZIP/Postal code: 12345
Country: United States
Email address: acme@acme.com
```

Answer (score 3):

Please don't start parsing emails. We do occasionally change the structure of our emails and email is inherently poor to base something as critical as your order management on.

We have PayPal [Instant Payment Notification](https://www.paypal.com/ipn) which takes care of all of this for you instead.
We've got sample code up on [GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples) for most major languages, as well as a 'HowTo' guide [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/).

PayPal's IPN, though created back quite a few years ago, is similar to what may now be commonly known as webhooks.
Whenever a transaction-related event occurs on your account, we trigger a HTTP POST request to a defined URL.

For security reasons, you should then take that POST payload, send it back to us and check for the response to ensure the HTTP POST you received is genuine.

I'd be happy to walk you through setting up IPN.
The easiest I can make it is:
1. Download the sample code
2. Set it up for your environment and make sure it accessible publicly
3. If you're using PayPal buttons, add:
`<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://url/to/your/ipn/script">`

Once you've got this, IPN works.

Alternatively, if you'd rather not specify your IPN URL in your buttons, you can simply enable it in your account via Profile > My selling tools > Instant Payment Notification and save the URL there.

Comment: Problem is, I am using a Windows server, and my programming skills are limited to BASIC and Pascal.  It's easier for me to parse an email than it is to learn PHP and figure out how to get it to work on a Windows server.  It should be a no-brainer for Paypal to append a parse-able section with field headers in an email notice to the seller.  Instead, you expect your clients to learn PHP.

Comment: @user1527613 Agreed. I understand that an approach like IPN is robust; however, it can be overkill for simple mom&pop shops which, as I understand it, are also part of PayPal's target audience. A script that parses plaintext email may be fragile, but changing that parsing on the rare occasion that it changes can still be way smaller effort than creating and managing that HTTP endpoint and all it entails.